# How can I make checking the value for the parameter?

Tags: python, json

I want to write a program that will save information from the API, in the form of a JSON file. The API has the `'exchangeId'` parameter. When I save information from the API, I want to save only those files in which the `'exchangeId'` will be different and his value will be more then one. How can I make it? Please, give me hand.

My Code:

```
exchangeIds = {102,311,200,302,521,433,482,406,42,400}

for pair in json_data["marketPairs"]:
   if (id := pair.get("exchangeId")):
     if id in exchangeIds:
     json_data["marketPairs"].append(pair)
     exchangeIds.remove(id)

     pairs.append({

       "exchange_name": pair["exchangeName"],
       "market_url": pair["marketUrl"],
       "price": pair["price"],
       "last_update" : pair["lastUpdated"],
       "exchange_id": pair["exchangeId"]

     })

     out_object["name_of_coin"] = json_data["name"]
     out_object["marketPairs"] = pairs
     out_object["pairs"] = json_data["numMarketPairs"]
            
     name = json_data["name"]
```

Example of ExchangeIds output, that I don't need:

```
{200} #with the one id in `ExchangeId`
```

Example of JSON output:

```
{
    "name_of_coin": "Pax Dollar",
    "marketPairs": [
        {
            "exchange_name": "Bitrue",
            "market_url": "https://www.bitrue.com/trade/usdp_usdt",
            "price": 1.0000617355334473,
            "last_update": "2021-12-24T16:39:09.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 433
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "Hotbit",
            "market_url": "https://www.hotbit.io/exchange?symbol=USDP_USDT",
            "price": 0.964348817699553,
            "last_update": "2021-12-24T16:39:08.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 400
        }
    ],
    "pairs": 22
}  #this one of exapmle that I need, because there are two id
```

Comment: share the json structure

Comment: @AlwaysSunny, I added the json structure